# IOS-SceneDelegate methods are not working after first background terminate

Tags: ios, xcode, background, terminate

I searched through stackoverflow but not saw any problem like this. The all sceneDelegate methods and applicationWillTerminate are not working after I terminate the project from background(swipe up). 
First opening of the project every methods works fine while I changing background to project or vice-versa, I can see them work by console. But when applicationWillTerminate func calls first time by background, then I can not see any methods are working. I open the app but not willResign func calls or even I terminate the from background not applicationWillTerminate works... Anyone knows the problem? Thank you.

Xcode Version 11.4.1 (last update)

-Also checked on my device but not work still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

When app terminates from background, Xcode suddenly breaks the attachment with simulator. To continue debugging on the same simulator, Debug > Attach to Process > 'Your Application'.